# Spring boot mongo repository Unsatisfied dependency while creating bean

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javabeans, mongorepository

I'm using Spring boot 2.2.7 with spring-data-mongodb. IDE : Intellij Idea Community Edition 2020.

I've a **common** project that hosts common models, repository and services and another one that hosts the controllers named **gateway**.
 Everything was working fine until I just renamed an enum from **NodeTypeEnum** to **PoductTypeEnum** in the **common** project.

when running the spring **gateway** application I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servicesConf': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catalogRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property nodeType found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

the code where the error comes from :

Enum (**common** project)

```
public enum ProductTypeEnum {
    SENSOR,
    FIELD,
    SINK,
    BASE_STATION,
    DATA_CENTER
}
```

class using the enum (**common** project)

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Document(collection = "catalog")
public class Product  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    /* internal UUID */
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private String uuId = new UdcId().getValue();
    @Indexed
    private ProductTypeEnum productType;
    ........
```

catalog repository (**common* project)

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
public interface CatalogRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

    @Query(sort = "{'model':1}")
    public List<Product> findAllByCapabilitiesContaining(String capability, Pageable paging);

    @Query(sort = "{'model':1}")
    public List<Product> findAllByModel(TextCriteria model, Pageable paging);

    @Query(sort = "{'model':1}")
    public List<Product> findAllByModelIsContainingIgnoreCase(String model, Pageable paging);


    @Query(sort = "{'model':1}")
    public List<Product> findAllByNodeType(ProductTypeEnum nodeType, Pageable paging);

    public List<Product> findAllByManufacturerIsContainingIgnoreCase(String manufacturer, Pageable paging);

    public Product findByUuId(String uuId);

    @Query(sort = "{'model':1}")
    public List<Product> findAllBy(Pageable paging);

}
```

service.conf (**gateway** project)

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class ServicesConf {

    @Autowired
    CatalogRepository catalogRepository;
    @Autowired
    ComponentRepository componentRepository;
    @Autowired
    ParamRepository paramRepository;
    @Autowired
    SensorRepository sensorRepository;
    @Autowired
    OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;
    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;


    @Bean
    CatalogPersistenceService catalogPersistenceService() {
        return new CatalogPersistenceService(catalogRepository, stockPersistenceService());
    }

    @Bean
    ParamPersistenceService paramPersistenceService() {
        return new ParamPersistenceService(paramRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    SensorPersistenceService sensorPersistenceService() {
        return new SensorPersistenceService(sensorRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    OrganizationPersistenceService organizationPersistenceService() {
        return new OrganizationPersistenceService(organizationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    StockPersistenceService stockPersistenceService() {
        return new StockPersistenceService(componentRepository, this.sensorPersistenceService());
    }

    @Bean
    SamplePersistenceService collectPersistenceService(){
        return new SamplePersistenceService(sampleRepository);
    }
}
```

It's very stange as it seems that an old nodeType property is memorized somewhere. I've checked that the jar produced by the **common** build project was uptodate in the maeven repository, it's ok. I've invalidate cache / restart Idea, rebuild project. even renaming the ProductTypeEnum back to NodeTypeEnum nothing fix the problem.

Any idea ?

thanks in advance.

---

**gateway** pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
    <artifactId>udc-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Gateway</name>
    <description>Gateway for UDC project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
            <artifactId>udc-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

**SOLUTION**

The spring-start-web dependency was missing in the **gateway** project pom.xml

Comment: Try to run `mvn clean install -U` in both projects

Comment: thank you @Ehab Qadah your solution fixed a another part of my problem. Actually it seems that idea doesn't always reload maven dependencies even if shown in the logs. The original issue was the spring-start-web missong in my gateway project pom.xml

Comment: @Emmanuel BRUNET I have exactly the same problem with you when renaming interface. I don't understund your solution. What do you means by adding "spring-start-web"? Can you give me the dependency ? I have already spring-boot-starter-web but always the same problem.